# Countvectorizer having words not in data

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I am new to sklearn and countvectorizer.

Some weird behaviour is happening to me.

Initializing the count vectorizer

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
document_mtrx = count_vect.fit_transform(df['description'])
count_vect.vocabulary_
count_vect.vocabulary_
Out[28]:
{u'viewscity': 36216,
 u'sizeexposed': 31584,
 u'rentalcontact': 29104,
 u'villagebldg': 36323,
```

Getting the rows which contains the word rentalcontact

```
df[df['description'].str.contains('rentalcontact')]
```

The number of rows returned is 0. Why is this the case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) has a parameter `lowercase` which defaults to `True` - most probably that's why you can't find those values.

So try this:

```
df[df['description'].str.lower().str.contains('rentalcontact')]
#                        ^^^^^^^
```

**UPDATE:**

> **vocabulary_ :** dict
>
> A mapping of terms to feature **indices**.

`u'rentalcontact': 29104` - means that `'rentalcontact'` has an index `29104` in the list of features.

I.e. `vectorizer.get_feature_names()[29104]` should return `'rentalcontact'`

Comment: the number of times this term occurred is 29104. However, when i ran my last line of code, it only returned 1 result. Is there something i am missing as well?

Comment: @aceminer, AFAIK `29104` is an index of `rentalcontact` in the sorted feature list. How to check: `print(vectorizer.get_feature_names()[29104])`

Comment: How do i get the frequency of the terms?

Comment: @aceminer, `document_mtrx.sum(0)` - will give you desired result